# How do I make emacs find `ac-source-pycomplete`?

Tags: python, auto-complete-mode

I followed [Jessica Hamrick's emacs setup](https://github.com/jhamrick/emacs) before adding `evil`. This means that there is a lot of specific configuration issues in my `~/.emacs.d/` which I don't necessarily understand, shame on me, but specifically I have checked that both `python-mode` and `auto-complete` were installed using `el-get`, and yet the `python-mode-hook` complains that it does not know about `ac-source-pycomplete`:

```
auto-complete error: (void-variable ac-source-pycomplete)
```

The symbol is explicitly added (with other symbols) to `ac-sources` as part of `'python-mode-hook`, because `pycomplete` thinks it's clever enough for all auto-completion tasks and removes all other sources from the `ac-sources`.

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
         (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-pycomplete
                            ac-source-yasnippet
                            ac-source-abbrev
                            ac-source-dictionary
                            ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))))
```

How do I get Emacs to know `pycomplete` in a clean-ish way?

Comment: No need to quote lambdas.

Comment: It seems that when `python-mode-hook` is run (when `python-mode` is enabled) `ac-source-pycomplete` has not yet been defined, which suggests that library autocomplete (or wherever `ac-source-pycomplete` is defined, if not by autocomplete) has not yet been loaded. Try `(require 'autocomplete)` before enabling `python-mode`.

Comment: `(require 'auto-complete)` is run by `init.el` and works in other modes. I don't start with any buffers in `python-mode`, so the `-hook` is definitely run later than `auto-complete` is loaded, unless I'm missing something crazy.

Comment: In that case, it would seem that `auto-complete.el` does not define `ac-source-pycomplete`. As I said, "*wherever  `ac-source-pycomplete` is defined*" - that library needs to be loaded before `ac-source-pycomplete` is, well, defined (not void). Find our what that library is, and load it before trying to use `python-mode`.

Comment: It appears that `'ac-source-pycomplete` is defined in [`python-mode/completion/auto-complete-pycomplete.el`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-mode-devs/python-mode/python-mode/view/head:/completion/auto-complete-pycomplete.el). It appears that even though I installed `python-mode` through `el-get`, it did not get added to the `load-path`, but everything else did. Curious.

Comment: See also [python-mode.el: ac-source-pycomplete undefined](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1403920) and [python-mode.el: pycomplete.el removes other useful sources](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1071441) in the Launchpad bug tracker for python-mode.el.

Answer (score 0):

When `python-mode-hook` is run (when `python-mode` is enabled) `ac-source-pycomplete` has not yet been defined, which indicates that the library where `ac-source-pycomplete` is defined has not yet been loaded.

Find out what that library is and ensure that you load it (e.g. using `require`)  before you enable `python-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me just by commenting out variable `ac-source-pycomplete` in `auto-complete-setting.el` while leaving everything intact. Then, Jedi mode takes care of AC in

```lisp
    ; hack to fix ac-sources after pycomplete.el breaks it
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
              '(lambda ()
                 (setq ac-sources '(;; ac-source-pycomplete
                                    ac-source-yasnippet
                                    ac-source-abbrev
                                    ac-source-dictionary
                                    ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))))
```